# How to model REST API with inherited entities?

Tags: java, spring, rest, inheritance, orm

I'd like to create a REST API endpoint that represents an user.
There are two entities that inherit from the user. (Student, Teacher)
How should I model this endpoint?

1. /api/users/students or /api/users/teachers (a separate controller for each)
2. /api/users?type=student (with query parameters)
3. other?

I'm using Spring with Spring Data JPA.
I've already created separate endpoints for each but I don't know if it makes sense.

Models without annotations, getters, setters, etc.

User

```
public class Student extends User {
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Date createdAt;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Student

```
public class Student extends User {
    private Class class;
    private Set<Mark> marks;
    private Set<Lesson> lessons;
}
```

Teacher

```
public class Teacher extends User {
    private Class educatedClass;
    private Set<Lesson> lessons;
    private Set<Subject> subjects;
}
```

I've seen other questions about that but I'm not sure what would be the best practise in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I'd like to create a REST API endpoint that represents an user. There are two entities that inherit from the user. (Student, Teacher) How should I model this endpoint?

REST doesn't care how many controllers you use to model your endpoints.  That's part of the point - you as an implementer have the freedom to change things in any way you like consistent with the uniform interface.

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your identifiers.  The machines don't try to extract any domain semantics from them; they are fundamentally opaque data.

In REST, the information that distinguishes teacher from student would normally live either in the [media type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838) (assuming that the two had different representation schema), or would be described by [links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) (when you are trying to distinguish the semantics of a URI).

[Atom Syndication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) and [AtomPub](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) are good specifications to read if you want to see how these ideas might be applied to a domain (web publishing).

Which means that you have the freedom as an implementer to choose identifier spellings that are convenient.  If a particular spelling makes it easier to split things out into different controllers, and you want to do that, then that spelling is a good choice for your case.

The machines really don't care much about distinctions like

```
/api/users/students
/api/users?students
/api/users?type=student
```

beyond some purely technical concerns (path segments and queries are handled differently in [relative uri resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2), HTML has built in support for application/x-www-form-urlencoded representations of key/value pairs, and so on).